# C# - Regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I'm studying a program written in c #.
I do not understand this regular expression, can you explain to me what it does?
Thank you

```
Match numberMatch = Regex.Match(patternOutput, "(#+)([\\.|,])(#+)");
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/ provides a convenient explanation to pretty much all possible kinds of regex syntaxes.

Comment: [Exactly, see regex101 fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/fAcRzM/1).

Answer (score 2):

https://regex101.com/ provides a convenient explanation to pretty much all possible kinds of regex syntaxes. In your case the regex matches a literal `#` character at the beginning, followed by one of the characters in the square brackets (each of them literally, where the backslash is escaped by another one): `[\\.|,]`, so this will match either `\`, `.`, `|`, `,`. And at the end follows one more `#` character.